# Given a T-SQL type as a string, what is the easiest way to evaluate it to a .Net Type?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, types

If given a string that contains a SQL Server/T-SQL datatype, what is the easiest way to evaluate the the string to a .Net Type?

For instance, if you have a string containing "*nvarchar*", the result returned by the conversion method should be a the `System.String` Type.  If I have a string containing "*int*", the result should be a `System.Int32` Type object.

I could easily write a function that takes a SQL datatype string and sends the string through a switch/case statement that returns a .Net Type object.  However, I wasn't sure if there was a function buried in the .Net framework that I overlooked that already does this.

What is the easiest/correct way to resolve a SQL Server datatype to a .Net datatype?

**ADDITIONAL CONTEXT**

In my case, I actually have a stored procedure that returns some meta-information about data.  Specifically, a string field is returned, containing a sql-type value which could be any sql-type that was available within SQL Server 2005.

My stored procedure has the potential to return any sql-type-- `int`, `smallint`, `datetime`, `binary`, etc.  I need to take this data type and convert it to a .Net `Type` object.

Matthew's comment below does provide all of the necessary mapping information, straight from Microsoft's documentation but, again, I was wondering if there was something integrated in either the `System.Data` or `System.Data.SqlClient` namespaces.

Comment: SQL-CLR type mapping: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx

Comment: If a string contains some data from SQL then the data is currently a string. Maybe some context would help.

Comment: Like @Matthew told, SQL-CLR Type Mapping is what you need.

Comment: Not really sure what you plan to do with it in .NET. Will simply storing it in a var not work for your purpose?

Comment: @Ellesedil: If the suggestion is to store that data returned from SQL as a `var`, that's not the point of my work. In my case I need to know how to handle data that will be inserted (or updated) into a data table.  If I don't have any data to evaluate, I can't derive the correct data type for storage in my DB.  Specifically, if you get a null value from SQL Server, .Net converts the null to a DBNull object, which tells me nothing about an underlying column definition.

Comment: I think you should go for the switch, its not like its going to be enormous.

Comment: If the value is null then why would you need to know the data type?  Null is the same for all.  If you want to interrogate the type of a column then interrogate the schema not the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing exposed that I know of. Deep in the System.Data.SqlClient code there is this function that is used to determine the type mapping:

```
internal Type GetTypeFromStorageType(bool isSqlType)
{
    if (isSqlType)
    {
        switch (this._type)
        {
            case StorageType.Empty:
                return null;

            case StorageType.Boolean:
                return typeof(SqlBoolean);

            case StorageType.Byte:
                return typeof(SqlByte);

            case StorageType.DateTime:
                return typeof(SqlDateTime);

            case StorageType.Decimal:
                return typeof(SqlDecimal);

            case StorageType.Double:
                return typeof(SqlDouble);

            case StorageType.Int16:
                return typeof(SqlInt16);

            case StorageType.Int32:
                return typeof(SqlInt32);

            case StorageType.Int64:
                return typeof(SqlInt64);

            case StorageType.Money:
                return typeof(SqlMoney);

            case StorageType.Single:
                return typeof(SqlSingle);

            case StorageType.String:
                return typeof(SqlString);

            case StorageType.SqlBinary:
                return typeof(object);

            case StorageType.SqlCachedBuffer:
                return typeof(SqlString);

            case StorageType.SqlGuid:
                return typeof(object);

            case StorageType.SqlXml:
                return typeof(SqlXml);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (this._type)
        {
            case StorageType.Empty:
                return null;

            case StorageType.Boolean:
                return typeof(bool);

            case StorageType.Byte:
                return typeof(byte);

            case StorageType.DateTime:
                return typeof(DateTime);

            case StorageType.Decimal:
                return typeof(decimal);

            case StorageType.Double:
                return typeof(double);

            case StorageType.Int16:
                return typeof(short);

            case StorageType.Int32:
                return typeof(int);

            case StorageType.Int64:
                return typeof(long);

            case StorageType.Money:
                return typeof(decimal);

            case StorageType.Single:
                return typeof(float);

            case StorageType.String:
                return typeof(string);

            case StorageType.SqlBinary:
                return typeof(byte[]);

            case StorageType.SqlCachedBuffer:
                return typeof(string);

            case StorageType.SqlGuid:
                return typeof(Guid);

            case StorageType.SqlXml:
                return typeof(string);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is about what I had suspected to find. I'm not afraid of long case statements and, in fact, it could be of more benefit to me because I can override certain types. Still, I prefer an integrated solution, if there was one, because it's easy to "miss" something with this type of operation, which could have dire consequences when working with critical data. You get a +1 and in a couple days, if there isn't a better answer, probably the answer mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try function below. I'm sure you can adjust it to your needs. If something is missed you will get exception:

```
    public static Type SqlTypeToType(string type)
    {
        string[] tokens = type.Split(new char[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string typeFamily = tokens[0].ToLowerInvariant();
        string size = tokens.Length > 1 ? tokens[1] : string.Empty;

        switch (typeFamily)
        {
            case "bigint":
                return typeof(long);
            case "binary":
                return size == "1" ? typeof(byte) : typeof(byte[]);
            case "bit":
                return typeof(bool);
            case "char":
                return size == "1" ? typeof(char) : typeof(string);
            case "datetime":
                return typeof(DateTime);
            case "datetime2":
                return typeof(DateTime);
            case "decimal":
                return typeof(decimal);
            case "float":
                return typeof(double);
            case "image":
                return typeof(byte[]);
            case "int":
                return typeof(int);
            case "money":
                return typeof(decimal);
            case "nchar":
                return size == "1" ? typeof(char) : typeof(string);
            case "ntext":
                return typeof(string);
            case "nvarchar":
                return typeof(string);
            case "real":
                return typeof(float);
            case "uniqueidentifier":
                return typeof(Guid);
            case "smalldatetime":
                return typeof(DateTime);
            case "smallint":
                return typeof(short);
            case "smallmoney":
                return typeof(decimal);
            case "sql_variant":
                return typeof(object);
            case "text":
                return typeof(string);
            case "time":
                return typeof(TimeSpan);
            case "tinyint":
                return typeof(byte);
            case "varbinary":
                return typeof(byte[]);
            case "varchar":
                return typeof(string);
            case "variant":
                return typeof(string);
            case "xml":
                return typeof(string);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("There is no .Net type specified for mapping T-SQL type '{0}'.", type));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yikes, don't use this. Mapping money & smallmoney to double? That's very dangerous.

Comment: @reedparkes, what's is your suggestion ? decimal?

Comment: @i-one: Yeah I think you should use decimal for money types. [This is a useful reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/sqlclient-for-ef-types) to help see the types that entity framework uses. Although it converts to it's own types, it's pretty clear to see which C# types they represent. Anyway, thanks for saving me some typing!